# jquery - reference input by name?

Tags: jquery, input, reference

The name of my form field is contact[0][state] and I'm trying to reference it via jquery to set a default value, but it's not working and I'm wondering if it's not working because of the brackets?

I'm trying:

```
$('input[name=concat[0][state]]').val('NY');
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

nevermind, you are missing quotes (").

try this:

```
$('input[name="concat[0][state]"]').val('NY');
```

I know the brackets would be a problem as an ID, but as a property it should work just fine as long as they are in quotes.

adding more info, you could also escape the brackets, but youy must still keep them in quotes.

```
$('input[name="concat\\[0\\]\\[state\\]"]').val('NY');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to double-escape the braces:

```
$("input[name=concat\\[0\\]\\[state\\]]").val('');
```

**Edit:** this appears to be [broken in jQuery 1.4.4](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/qk7kG/1/), but [it works in 1.4.3](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/qk7kG/).

Comment: that'd be the case if it was an ID, but as a value of a property it should be fine if its enclosed in quotes.

Comment: @Victor: brackets aren't valid in IDs, whether they're escaped or not.  This almost certainly will work, but I wasn't sure exactly how good the jQuery selector parser is to feel confident recommending quotes as the solution.

Comment: @Andy Can you provide a demo? It doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/P5Pef/

Comment: How about docs: *"If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \\."* EDIT: Seems like it should work according to the docs. Strange.

Comment: @andy I know for IDs, but I believe they are ok as property values.

Comment: I cannot get this to work, but enclosing in quotes as I said does. see @Sime jsfiddle link

Comment: @patrick, @Šime: Looks like double-escaping is broken in 1.4.4!

Comment: this would work if you enclosed your value in quotes as well, which would explain the specification posted by patrick. try this: $("input[name='concat\\\[0\\\]\\\[state\\\]']").val('');

Comment: @andy no you just needed to enclose in quotes. if you do then it works.

Comment: @Victor: see the update in my answer.  It **should** work without the quotes - see the 1.4.3 link, but they broke it in jQuery 1.4.4.  Your solution does work, however, I tested that too.

Comment: I wonder if this is a recent addition to the docs, but it now states: *"value: An attribute value. Quotes are mandatory."* http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: @patrick: yes, that is recent.  Quotes used to be optional - I guess they changed it to properly reflect CSS selectors, which also require quotes.

Comment: That's an important change. I can't find it in any release notes.

Comment: @patrick: me either, perhaps it was deprecated a while ago.  You'd think a potentially breaking change like that would be noted when removed, unless it wasn't intended to be removed just yet - the smart thing would have been to update the docs, deprecate the behavior and then remove it in the next major release.